# Charging card with Stripe

Tags: php, stripe-payments

Everything is working fine in Stripe - the token is generated, written in the "log" part in my dashboard, etc. However there is no charge done. I got no error from Stripe or my code even if I did all the error handling given by the stripe documentation. How can I correct this?

```
require_once ("vendor/autoload.php");

if ($_POST) {
 echo "catch if";

 // Set your secret key: remember to change this to your live secret key in production
 // See your keys here: https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys

 StripeStripe::setApiKey("myApyKey");

 // Get the credit card details submitted by the form

 $token = $_POST['stripeToken'];

 // Create a charge: this will charge the user's card

 try {
  echo "charging";
  $charge = StripeCharge::create(array(
   "amount" => 1000, // Amount in cents
   "currency" => "eur",
   "source" => $token,
   "description" => "Example charge"
  ));
 }

 catch(StripeErrorCard $e) {

  // Since it's a decline, \Stripe\Error\Card will be caught

  $body = $e->getJsonBody();
  $err = $body['error'];
  print ('Status is:' . $e->getHttpStatus() . "\n");
  print ('Type is:' . $err['type'] . "\n");
  print ('Code is:' . $err['code'] . "\n");

  // param is '' in this case

  print ('Param is:' . $err['param'] . "\n");
  print ('Message is:' . $err['message'] . "\n");
 }

 catch(StripeErrorRateLimit $e) {

  // Too many requests made to the API too quickly

 }

 catch(StripeErrorInvalidRequest $e) {

  // Invalid parameters were supplied to Stripe's API

 }

 catch(StripeErrorAuthentication $e) {

  // Authentication with Stripe's API failed
  // (maybe you changed API keys recently)

 }

 catch(StripeErrorApiConnection $e) {

  // Network communication with Stripe failed

 }

 catch(StripeErrorBase $e) {

  // Display a very generic error to the user, and maybe send
  // yourself an email

 }

 catch(Exception $e) {

  // Something else happened, completely unrelated to Stripe

 }
```

Comment: Your catches are mostly silently failing. Either remove them or have them do something obvious, like `print "OH SHIT Stripe InvalidRequest";`

Comment: try after this line  $err = $body['error']; print_r($err); and see error.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably getting an error, and your code is handling that error correctly, but you error handling code doesn't actually *do* anything for many of the cases.

You should probably add something (such as a `print` call) in each `catch` block to see exactly what type of issue is being returned.

Alternatively, your Stripe Dashboard has a way to view your accounts Live Mode and Test Mode logs at https://dashboard.stripe.com/logs which will contain an entry for every request (successful or otherwise) that hit Stripe's servers.

Comment: I found the problem !!

Comment: Actually my API wasn't up to date ! Apparently Stripe didn't feel like telling me that it was that important :)

Comment: They probably were telling you. Your do-nothing `catch` statements probably hid that from you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use below code find error issue

```
try {
  echo "charging";
  $charge = StripeCharge::create(array(
   "amount" => 1000, // Amount in cents
   "currency" => "eur",
   "source" => $token,
   "description" => "Example charge"
  ));
 }

 catch(StripeErrorCard $e) {
    $error = $e->getJsonBody();
    <pre>print_r($error);</pre>
    //then you can handle like that 
    if($error == "Your card was declined."){
      echo "Your credit card was declined. Please try again with an alternate card.";
     }
 }
```